# How to fix alpha of stb_image library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, graphics

I'm using stb_image.c for loading bytes of data to opengl.
However, I'm struggling with one issue that happens to me, when I try to load png files with alpha channel[image]

Now the white area should be the transparent one, though it cleared only the little part of it.
Any ideas what is causing this behavior?

[image]

The photoshop histogram

Comment: Exactly what values does your alpha image (the .png) contain?

Comment: What do you mean? How do I get those?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you have at hand. If you posted it [as a 8-bit grayscale image], it would probably be possible to see what it looks like. Or load it up in a photo editor type program, and inspect it there?

Comment: Well, I've just opened it in photoshop, and it looks good, even while it's grayscale

Comment: What's your alpha blending mode set to? (i.e. parameters to `glBlendFunc`?)

Comment: "good" means what exactly? What are the pixel values?

Comment: @Cameron I'm using these values `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Comment: @MatsPetersson by "good" I mean that it is absolutely transparent in PHOTOSHOP. The pixel values... I'm gonna update my question with the histogram from the photoshop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the Tom Dalling OpenGL tutorial? ^^

I don't know if you are still searching for a solution to this but here I go anyways:
I actually had the same problem as I was working through that lesson but it worked for me by using glBlendFunc with sfactor GL_SRC_ALPHA and dfactor GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA. These are the parameters OpenGL seems to recommend in the documentation at least: [glBlendFunc](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml)

> Transparency is best implemented using blend function(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) with primitives sorted from farthest to nearest. Note that this transparency calculation does not require the presence of alpha bitplanes in the frame buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find your answer the most accurate one and working, though it depends on the configuration of openGL, in particular the blend function.